# Websphere JTA transaction configuration

Tags: spring, websphere, jta

I am trying to configure spring JTA transaction using websphereUOMmanager

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager">
 </bean>
```

I am getting this exception.

```
 Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager] to required type [javax.transaction.TransactionManager] for property 'transactionManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I have deleted all the Javax.usertransaction jars but still the same

This din't work for me

```
<bean id="tranSactionManager"
    class="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" 
    factory-bean="transactionManager"
    factory-method="getTransactionManager">
</bean>
```

This also din't worked for me

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Tried this one this din't work

```
 <tx:jta-transaction-manager>
```

Tried this too

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/comp/TransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Tried parent first loading classes setting and tried parent last nothing works

I am using jdk 1.6, spring 4.0.7, websphere 8.5 can any one know what the problem is? i used auto wire and gave value = constructor that din't worked . 
This is my stack trace

```
[8/26/15 20:01:44:425 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.425 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:425 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.425 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:425 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.425 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'transactionManager' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[8/26/15 20:01:44:441 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.441 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'transactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:441 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.441 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/UserTransaction]
[8/26/15 20:01:44:441 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.441 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.t.j.WebSphereUowTransactionManager - JTA UserTransaction found at default JNDI location [java:comp/UserTransaction]
[8/26/15 20:01:44:441 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.441 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.t.j.WebSphereUowTransactionManager - Retrieving WebSphere UOWManager from default JNDI location [java:comp/websphere/UOWManager]
[8/26/15 20:01:44:441 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.441 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/websphere/UOWManager]
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'tranSactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'tranSactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'tranSactionManager' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'tranSactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'wmqConnectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:456 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.456 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'wmqConnectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:472 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.472 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'wmqConnectionFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[8/26/15 20:01:44:472 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.472 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults - Not strongly caching class [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory] because it is not cache-safe
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'wmqConnectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'connectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'connectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'connectionFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'wmqConnectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'com.lmig.cm.common.security.utils.CMSecurityUtils#d8cdcfb8'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'com.lmig.cm.common.security.utils.CMSecurityUtils#d8cdcfb8'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'connectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'connectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dialm1'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'dialm1'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:519 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.519 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'db' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[8/26/15 20:01:44:534 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.534 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'connectionFactory'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:534 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.534 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:534 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.534 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'dialm1'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:534 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.534 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:534 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.534 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:550 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.550 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'dataSource' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[8/26/15 20:01:44:569 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.569 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
[8/26/15 20:01:44:571 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.571 [server.startup : 0] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils - No property editor [javax.transaction.TransactionManagerEditor] found for type javax.transaction.TransactionManager according to 'Editor' suffix convention
[8/26/15 20:01:44:603 EDT] 00000044 SystemOut     O 20:01:44.603 [server.startup : 0] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [springConfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager' to required type 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' for property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager] to required type [javax.transaction.TransactionManager] for property 'transactionManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Any suggestions pls

Comment: Why are you even injecting a transaction manager? That shouldn't be needed looks like you are doing something you shouldn't be doing in the first place. Why does your `DataSource` require a transaction manager? The datasource should come from JNDI...

Comment: I am doing an XA transaction with database

Comment: So... You are still doing something you shouldn't be doing... Your datasources should be a simple jndi lookup and nothing more...

Comment: After you mentioned i removed the datasource configuration and added a jndi lookup now i am getting this exception            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250948/because-of-no-bean-could-be-found-in-the-registry-of-type-platformtransactionma