# because of No bean could be found in the registry of type: PlatformTransactionManager

Tags: spring, apache-camel, websphere, jta

I am trying to configure the spring transaction policy

```
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager">
 </bean>


<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">      
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />    
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" />    
</bean>
```

this is my exception

```
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry of type: PlatformTransactionManager
```

I don't know why i am getting that exception. Can anyone help?

This is my Stack Trace.Hope this helps

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route RetryableRoute at: >>> Transacted[] <<< in route: Route(RetryableRoute)[[From[direct:start]] -> [Transacted[]]... because of No bean could be found in the registry of type: PlatformTransactionManager
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:910) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:175) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:780) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2068) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1816) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1683) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1651) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:157) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:68) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:296) [na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry of type: PlatformTransactionManager
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.doResolvePolicy(TransactedDefinition.java:234) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.resolvePolicy(TransactedDefinition.java:168) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.createProcessor(TransactedDefinition.java:145) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:499) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:212) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:907) ~[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Instead of snippets post the full stack trace.

Comment: Yup added the stack trace

Comment: Looks like your apache camel with spring integration is not correctly setup.

Comment: What do you mean by that ?  http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html i am using the same setup which they mentioned in camel website

Comment: The fact that you follow part of configuration does mean it works. I guess there needs to be more done for proper integration. That is basically what the stack trace is telling you, judging from that camel isn't aware of the stuff you are doing in your file. Looks like it is loaded in a completely different context as camel.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not help with the original question, but I came here looking for a solution to:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry of type: PlatformTransactionManage
```

while trying to setup transactions for a SQL data-source for an apache camel route and found that specifying it like, in camel-context.xml:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mydatasource"/>
</bean>
```

Solves my issue.